# Cast a Linq result set to an interface

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
var result = context.BEntries
    .Where(x => x.a == "a")
    .Select(x => new MyClass()
    {
        a = x.a
    }).ToList();
```

I get a result of type `List<MyClass>`. However, I must return `IEnumerable<IMyclass>`. How do I cast this to its generic definition?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to.

`IEnumerable<T>` is covariant; `List<MyClass>` is implicitly convertible to `IEnumerable<IMyClass>`.

---

.Net 3.5 does not use covariance, so you'll need to cast it yourself.

You can either call `.Cast<IMyClass>()` or cast the `select` expression to `IMyClass` so that the query returns `IMyClass` in the first place.

Comment: This assumes C# 4 or later, no?

Comment: This is a C# 3.5 project.

Comment: I also wrote this in the other answer: This look like it, but I'm getting this error: `{"Unable to cast the type 'MyClass' to type 'IMyClass'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."}` The contents of the class are pretty much basic types, some nullable.

Comment: If you're writing an EF query, you need to run that on the client by calling `AsEnumerable()` first.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an older version of C# that does not support [covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx), you can use `Cast`:

```
var result = context.BEntries
                    .Where(x => x.a == "a")
                    .Select(x => new MyClass() { a = x.a })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Cast<IMyClass>();
```

Comment: This look like it, but I'm getting this error: `{"Unable to cast the type 'MyClass' to type 'IMyClass'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."}`

The contents of the class are pretty much basic types, some nullable.

Comment: @elite5472: I've added an `AsEnumerable` (based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1361100/1149773)); check whether it works now.

Answer (score 0):

As long as MyClass implements IMyClass this should be fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `var`, simple define a `List` or `IEnumerable` of your interface