# Casting Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, expression

I have the following expression

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<IUserFile, bool>> filter
```

I want to convert this to (IUserFile to UserFile)

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<UserFile, bool>> filter
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why? Seems like you're trying to hammer a screw :)

Comment: I think this is the same problem as here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361085/cast-linq-results-to-listmyinterface  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145847/entity-framework-linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-entity-data-model-primi

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast the first to the second as `Expression<Func<IUserFile, bool>>` is a different type then `Expression<Func<UserFile, bool>>`.

But you could wrap it:

```
Expression<Func<UserFile, bool>> userFileFilter = 
    userFile => filter.Compile()(userFile);
```

Tested with the following example in LINQPad: http://pastebin.com/R6xz4chH

If the first expression does not change you can also "pre-compile" it:

```
var filterComplied = filter.Compile();
Expression<Func<UserFile, bool>> userFileFilter = 
    userFile => filterCompiled(userFile);
```

Comment: `Func<T, TResult>` is variant, so you can cast `Func<IUserFile, bool>` to `Func<UserFile, bool>`. That's not a problem.

Comment: Hmm, did not know that - I though generics do not support this. Let me try it out...